# Copy & paste in a terminal without SHIFT

Tags: terminal, keyboard-shortcuts, terminal-emulator

In all terminal emulators that I know of, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is used for sending control codes such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>. On most systems this conflicts with common keyboard shortcuts.

Thus on all those systems except OS X, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd> is used for copy-pasting and more, which I find really annoying. If I got a penny for every time I opened the Firefox inspector accidentally, I would be rich.

I tried mimicking Apples behavior of using <kbd>Cmd</kbd> for keyboard shortcuts, but this is practically impossible to achieve across the whole desktop.

The other alternative is to use another combination for sending control codes. Is there any terminal emulator that supports this?

I found Sakura allows setting the modifier for key combos, but not for control characters.
Another desirable feature is non-messed-up line wrapping, but that is of secondary importance.

Comment: If `vi` is your thing you can set your terminal in vi mode: `$ set -o vi` and everything you do in `vi` can be done on terminal.

Comment: On *nix systems you selecting anything copies it to the clipboard (well, one of them) and middle clicking pastes. No need for a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: I'd suggest looking through the back catalog of Q&A on U&L, specifically: ["unix clipboard"](http://unix.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=unix%20clipboard). The Unix clipboard is much more sophisticated than the Windows one you're familiar with. There are multiple clipboards as well as a whole host of tools for interacting with them.

Comment: What are you talking about... Selecting text in my terminal does not copy anything. I'm not familiar with Windows. I use vi mode already, but `esc, v` does not let me select and yank stuff.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can change your settings in Gnome Terminal keyboard settings to make

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> = Copy
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> = Paste

Menu > Edit > Keyboard Shortcuts...
[image: Gnome Keyboard Shortcuts Settings]

Then you can still press <kbd>Shift</kbd> to do whatever that key combination would usually do in a terminal, e.g.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> = Interrupt
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> = Literal Next Character

---

Alternatively, you could get into the habit of using

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Ins</kbd> = Copy
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> = Cut
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ins</kbd> = Paste

in all applications, to avoid ever accidentally pressing  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in your terminal and having it abort the program instead of copying some text.  Those shortcuts date back to the [IBM Common User Access standards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Common_User_Access).  Some people might remember them from  DOS EDIT.

Comment: How to do that under xfce terminal ?

Comment: You, Sir, made my day! I'm appalled how long I lived with ctrl+shift+c/v and all the havoc confusing them between applications has caused considering how easy this fix was.

Answer (score 4):

With the [kitty terminal](https://sw.kovidgoyal.net/kitty/) you can set this configuration option (not default, but nice):

`map ctrl+c copy_or_interrupt`

Then when you hit Ctrl-C, it will copy if something is selected, but if nothing is selected, it'll send the regular Interrupt signal.

Answer (score 1):

You can also select text and paste by clicking with the mouse scroller...

Answer (score 0):

I'm a fan of [Parcellite](http://parcellite.sourceforge.net/). It can copy content on selection and paste on mouse middle click. It is much faster than using keyboard shortcuts. Give it a try.

Comment: +1 but that has nothing to do with parcelite, select to copy and middle click paste is default *nix behavior.